# Array being turned into string in hash table

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, type-conversion

I have an array being returned to me which I am stepping through with the foreach,  I want to use one element of each member of that array in a hash table that will be converted to a json object.  When I add the element to a powershell array object and then add it to the hash the strings are being combined instead of added as arrays.

Spec

```
"destinationInterclusterLifIps": [
  "172.31.5.119",
  "172.31.15.103"
]
```

Actual return:

```
"destinationInterclusterLifIps":  [
     "172.31.33.150172.31.42.41"
 ],
```

Building the array

```
if(!$destinationInterclusterLifIps){
    $destinationInterclusterLifIps =  @()
    foreach($record in $interclusterIpInfo.peerInterClusterLifs){
        $destinationInterclusterLifIps += $record.address
    }
}
```

Hash table

```
$body = @{
        destinationInterclusterLifIps = @($destinationInterclusterLifIps)
}
```

This has to be something simple with hash tables that I am missing

Comment: PowerShell's auto-collection-feature-thingy could reduce this to just `$interclusterIpInfo.peerInterClusterLifs.address` without the need for looping.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: That thingy doesn't have a name in the official docs, unfortunately; the closest thing we have to an official names is _member enumeration_, in the [blog post that announced the feature in v3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/06/13/new-v3-language-features/). It's the name I've been using in my answers here on SO, notably in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) that tries to explain the feature comprehensively.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that. I'm not a big fan of that name -- it sounds quite ambiguous with, you know, enumerating the individual members, but I suppose it's better than nothing.

Comment: Agreed on both counts, @JeroenMostert. The docs now at least [describe the behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_properties?view=powershell-6#properties-of-scalar-objects-and-collections) (superficially), but without giving it a name, so at least hypothetically a better name could be chosen.

Comment: On second thought, @JeorenMostert: coming up with names that are both expressive and concise is difficult, and _member enumeration_ isn't half bad: _enumeration_ covers the aspect of operating on all elements of a collection, and _member_ covers what is being accessed on each element.

Comment: Update: The official name that was chosen is [_member-access enumeration_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration), and I've updated my previous answers accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Your code alone doesn't explain the symptom, but [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55303593/45375) hints at an **interesting pitfall** that is worth exploring:

- **By default, a PowerShell variable can accept a value of any type**, and values of different types can be assigned at any time:

  ```bash
  $var = 42   # $var now contains an [int]
  # ...
  $var = 'hi' # $var now contains a [string]
  ```
- However, **you can *type-constrain* variables, in which case they only ever accept values of that type** - **or values that can automatically be *converted* to that type** (PowerShell is very flexible when it comes to automatic conversions):

  ```bash
  # Create a type-constrained variable.
  [int] $var = 42  # $var now contains an [int] AND is locked into storing [int]s

  # Try to assign a [string] that CANNOT be converted to an [int]
  $var = 'hi' # FAILS: 'Cannot convert value "hi" to type "System.Int32"...'

  # Try to assign a [string] that CAN be converted to an [int]
  $var = ' 42  ' # OK - string was converted; $var now contains [int] 42
  ```

Typically, but not necessarily, *parameter variables* are type-constrained, as part of a script or function's list of declared parameters.

If you later *reuse* a type-constrained parameter variable by assigning a new value to it, it will enforce its original type, as described above.

The likeliest explanation in your case is that your **`$destinationInterclusterLifIps` was declared as a type-constrained `[string] $destinationInterclusterLifIps` parameter**, in which case a later **attempt to assign an *array* resulted in *implicit stringification* of that array**; to illustrate with a simple example:

```bash
function foo {
  param(
   # Type-constrained parameter.
   [string] $destinationInterclusterLifIps
  )

  # ...

  # Try to assign an *array*:
  # Instead of storing an array, the [string] type constraint 
  # converts the array to a *single string*, as a space-separated list of
  # its elements.
  $destinationInterclusterLifIps = 1, 2, 3

  # Output the value.
  $destinationInterclusterLifIps

}

# Call the function (no argument needed)
foo
```

This outputs:

```bash
1 2 3
```

i.e., the array converted to a *string*, as a space-separated list of its elements.
(An array would print element by element, each on its own line).

Note that your problem was therefore unrelated to the use of a [*hash table*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) and its conversion to JSON - it's just where you happened to notice the problem.

---

**Optional reading: Modifying / removing a variable's type constraint**:

It is possible to later recreate a type-constrained variable with a *different* type; e.g.:

```bash
[int] $var = 42; [string] $var = 'hi'
```

While you can use `Remove-Variable` to effectively *remove* a type constraint by removing the variable first and then recreating it unconstrained, as [Maximilian Burszley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8188846/maximilian-burszley) suggests - 
`[int] $var = 42; Remove-Variable var; $var = 'hi'` - you can use `[object] $var = 'hi'` as a shortcut, since type-constraining to `[object]` is tantamount to *not* constraining the value.

`(Get-Variable var).Attributes` contains a variable's attributes, and a type-constraining attribute is stored as a `[System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute]` instance. If you're not concerned about removing *all* attributes, another simple, though obscure, option for removing a type constraint is to use `(Get-Variable var).Attributes.Clear()`.

Comment: Thanks.  Isn't `[psobject]` preferred for performance as the boxing/unboxing of `[object]` doesn't need to happen?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: [What is `[psobject]`?](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5579). [Never heard of it](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5551). But, seriously, I prefer to keep explicit use of `[psobject]` out of my PowerShell code - I wouldn't worry about performance here, but a quick test shows, surprisingly, that using `[psobject]` actually slows things down: `$a=1..1e5; tcm { foreach($i in $a) { [object] $v = 1 } }, { foreach($i in $a) { [psobject] $v = 1 } }`; `tcm` = https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was having a conflict with a variable.  Maybe because it is being used as a param as well.  Setting the variable to any other name cleared the issue.

```
if(!$sourceInterclusterLifIps){
    $InterclusterIPSource =  @()
    foreach($record in $interclusterIpInfo.interClusterLifs){
        $InterclusterIPSource += $record.address
    }
} else {
    $InterclusterIPSource = $sourceInterclusterLifIps
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try using an ArrayList with .add(), It should do what you want.

```
$destinationInterclusterLifIps = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
if(!$destinationInterclusterLifIps){
$destinationInterclusterLifIps =  @()
foreach($record in $interclusterIpInfo.peerInterClusterLifs){
    $destinationInterclusterLifIps.add( $record.address )
}
```

}

Comment: While this may be more efficient (though it will hardly matter in this case), it neither explains Nicholas' problem nor does it provide a solution, given that it is functionally equivalent to the original code (except for the specific collection type, but that doesn't matter).